# Cannot point to webroot directory in plugin folder in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to point javascript and css file to webroot directory in plugin folder.
This is my code of the view in the plugin directory

> echo
>   $this->Html->css('/PanelAdmin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');

but this code points to webroot of my parent application. Here PanelAdmin is 
the plugin name.
Please help to sort out my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include CSS assets from a plugin you need to use the plugin dot notation. For example, if you wanted to include the file `css/styles.css` from your `PanelAdmin` plugin you would use:-

```
echo $this->Html->css('PanelAdmin.styles');
```

See the [official docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#linking-to-assets-in-plugins) for details.

Cake uses `cssBaseUrl` to determine the folder name for the `css` folder, but I believe you can navigate out of this by using `../` in the file path:-

```
echo $this->Html->css('PanelAdmin.../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```